# How do I log for debugging purposes in Visual studio web performance and load test?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, logging

I am debugging a Visual studio (2010) web load test.  One cannot debug when running as load test, only as "single" test.
I would like something like Console.WriteLine, Trace.WriteLine or Debug.WriteLine

Is there anything like this built-in or do I have to setup log4net/nlog/whatever?

Answer (score 1):

`Trace.WriteLine` should work - if you run DebugView from Sysinternals (free, available from Microsoft) as Administrator I do see the Trace.WriteLine dumped out.

My sample code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    internal class Program {
        private static void Main ( string[] args ) {
          Trace.WriteLine ( "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" );
        }
    }
}
```

The debug view shows this:

[image]

It shows a lot of more entries as Visual Dtudio, drivers and probably other applications might also have calls to the underlying API. So you might want to use a filter or highlight.

One additional hint: DebugView captures the output for one machine.